# call or get username values from servlet to jsp on successful of login in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I have created a simple login form with username and password with database connectivity and to validate it properly. For this I did the following:

1.> **Login.java**

```
package roseindia.net;

import java.io.*;

//import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import java.sql.*;

/*** Servlet implementation class Login
***/
@WebServlet(description = "Login Servlet", urlPatterns = { "/login" })
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Login() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
     */
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("We are service method of servlet");

        /*
        String username="user";
        String password="root";
        */


        String un=request.getParameter("username");
        String pw=request.getParameter("password");

        String msg=" ";

        Connection conn=null;
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbName="userlogindb";
        String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String dbUserName="root";
        String dbPassword="root";

        try{
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,dbUserName,dbPassword);
        String strQuery="select * from usertable where username='" + un + "' and  password='" + pw + "'";
        Statement st= conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(strQuery);
        if(rs.next())
        {
            msg="Hello "    + un + "! Your login is successful";
        request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
        RequestDispatcher    req=request.getRequestDispatcher("/successful.jsp"); 
                req.forward(request, response);
            } else
        {

            RequestDispatcher req=request.getRequestDispatcher("/failed.jsp"); 
        req.forward(request, response);
        msg="Hello "    + un + "! Your login failed";
    }
    rs.close();
    st.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*
    if(un.equals(username) && pw.equals(password))
    {
       msg="Hello " + un + "! Your login is successful"; 
    }
    else
    {
       msg="Hello " + un + "! Your login failed"; 
    }
    */
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println("<font size='6' color=red>" + msg + "</font>");


}

}
```

2.> **successful.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Successful</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Login Successful</h2>
<%Object value = request.getAttribute("value");%>
<p><%=value%></p>
</body>
</html>
```

3.> **failed.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Failed</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Login Failed</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

4.> I have added all the necessary jar files and program is running and validating properly.

But the problem is that it not showing username when successfully login. Where I doing wrong.
Also I want to know how to fetch username from database in my successful.jsp page so that it can be viewed.
When I m using Object it is showing me the output **null**

Comment: are you sure `request.setAttribute("msg", msg);` is executed?I mean does `if` returns true?

Comment: yes it is returning null value JqueryLearner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `msg` instead of `value` in `jsp` as you are setting `msg` attribute in `login.java`.

Try this:

```
<%Object value = request.getAttribute("msg");%>
```

Also note that you must use `PreparedStatements` with placeholders to avoid `sql injection` like:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from usertable where username=? and  password=?");
pstmt.setString(1,userName);
pstmt.setString(2,password);
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Also have a look at [how to avoid java code in jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/1551233).

Comment: Bhushan correct it works and your advice I will definitely consider that is mistake from my end I got it